# Red line in code vba Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CdDfhnoDPXkFVmJWIiUlv3BZ1u-jP9Pn
Error when I use Excel 2007, but in Excel 2013 then it normal
code:

```
#If Win64 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
#Else
    Public Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
#End If


#If Win64 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
#Else
    Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
        ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
#Else
    Public Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
        ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
#End If


#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
        (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
#Else
    Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
        (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#End If
```

Unlike `Win64` which just checks the OS version, `VBA7` checks whether your office suite is 64-bit (as opposed to 32-bit). Since you can't use 64-bit Office on a 32-bit OS, this essentially covers you in both cases.

And even if you are using a 32-bit office suite within a 64-bit OS, you are still covered because of the fact your 32-bit suite will use 32-bit memory pointers anyway. Your OS may have to convert them, but that's the OS' problem to deal with.

In the case you prefer the redundancy, however, you can use the `And` operator to check for both:

```
#If VBA7 And Win64
```

But me personally, I just go with the `VBA7` statement.

> The "red line" you speak of will not affect your code. It's because one of the two statements is invalid, but because you are using the `#IF...#Then` statement in your declarations you will not throw an error.